# Use > or < sign dynamically in an excel formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula which picks ">" or "<" sign depending upon whether any record has "Higher" or "Lower" against it.

For example, if A1 has "Higher", then formula in B1 should be =0.78>0.59

If A2 has "Lower", then formula in B2 should be =0.78<0.59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
if(a1="higher", 0.78>0.59, 0.78<0.59)
'alternate
=or(and(a1="higher", 0.78>0.59), and(a1="lower", 0.78<0.59))
```

Answer (score 0):

use this as formula.
=IF(A1>B1,">","<") in cell C.
than use this formula to get your desired look in next cell. =CONCATENATE(A2,C2,B2)

You can hide Column C if you don't want to show it.

Check it by clicking following link,

[image: Screen shot of above work]

Comment: i was thinking that this should be based on values in cell, however if you want to show a specific phrase based on higher and lower word, than above mentioned answer will work.